# "Unexpected @ in program" when copying Facebook's Share Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I've copied the code from Facebook's developer site to integrate Facebook sharing into my app:

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@whatsyourinneragefb:inner_age
                                        title:@Sample Inner Age
                                        image:@https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png
                                          url:@http://samples.ogp.me/578838518886846
                                  description:@];;

[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/objects/whatsyourinneragefb:inner_age"
                                   graphObject:object
                             completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                 id result,
                                                 NSError *error) {
                                 // handle the result
                             }];
```

However, the "@" before `@whatsyourinneragefb` produces the error `"Unexpected @ in program`. Also, the lines such as `@https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png` have the @https: in white, and the rest highlighted green, as though it were a comment, so I feel this wouldn't work even if the above error was gone. So:

How can I solve the first error?

and

Is the code functional, or does it need to be tweaked to work?

All help appreciated.

Comment: Where did you copy it from?

Comment: I strongly suggest reading *at least* the very basics of the objective-c language before asking a question such as this on SO. I suggest reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I went to my app in "My Apps" in the Facebook Developer site, then went to Open Graph, and clicked "Get Code".

Comment: Totally agree with `David` if you don't understand the basics then you need to start all over from the beginning. Never just copy and paste code type it out yourself because then you learn what it does and you can spot the errors that are in the code if there are any which if this is copied code there are.

Comment: Thanks for the advice David and Popeye - I'll take it onboard in the future. I would definitely prefer to know why the code I'm putting in my app does rather than just whacking it in there.

Answer (score 3):

String Literals in Objective-C look like `@"this"`.

So change `@Sample Inner Age` to `@"Sample Inner Age"`, for example.

Comment: Would I do this for "inner_age" also? This now produces the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'Inner age'"

Comment: Yes, like `@"whatsyourinneragefb:inner_age"`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you copied that code from; I couldn't find any reference to "Inner Age" on the Facebook developer site. It's possible that you misinterpretted how you were to edit the source they provided. A correct implementation using your injected data would provide the string literals with quotation marks as such (you're also missing a description):

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"whatsyourinneragefb:inner_age"
                                    title:@"Sample Inner Age"
                                    image:@"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png"
                                      url:@"http://samples.ogp.me/578838518886846"
                              description:@"<you're missing a description>"];

[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/objects/whatsyourinneragefb:inner_age"
                               graphObject:object
                         completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                             id result,
                                             NSError *error) {
                             // handle the result
                         }];
```